# jQuery if specific text exists in table hide first td of his row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I was wondering how to solve the following:
I have a table with several rows. What I want is this: check whether a specific text exists, actually "expired" if so hide the first TD of **that row only**.

This is my working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justamir/chsgf50t/1/)

and this is my JS code so far:

```
var $existingText = $('#myTable');
  if ($existingText.length); {
    if ($existingText.text().replace(/\s+/g, '') === "expired") {
    $(this).parents("tr td:first-child").css('display','none');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work here

```
$existingText.find('tr').each(function(){
    if($(this).text().indexOf('expired') > -1){
        $(this).find('td:first-child').hide()
    }
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/chsgf50t/5/)

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
$('#myTable td:contains(expired)').siblings('td:first-child').hide();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/chsgf50t/4/)

Answer (score 0):

It is working:

```
$("tr:has(td:contains('expired'))").each(function () {
    $(this).find("td:first").hide();
});
```